# Will this code break?

Tags: c#, nullable

A business object is returning a `short?` datatype.

How would I get this value into a variable?

```
short? myShort = SomeBusinessObject.UserBlah;
```

Is that correct? Will it break if it is null?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you think might be null. Many of the answers are making assumptions about what UserBlah returns. My guess (and hence my answer) is that you're trying to protect against SomeBusinessObject being null. However, that's a guess and more info would be good.

Answer (score 4):

That's correct. You only have to worry if you're assigning myShort to a non-nullable short, in which case you have to check HasValue, like so:

```
short s = myShort.HasValue ? myShort.Value : (short) 0; // or some other short value
```

Comment: Even better. I use this syntax because the default is 0, and we use *.MinValue if the DB value is null. We're still transitioning to nullable types with a legacy system.

Comment: Use the null coalesce operator instead of the above pattern.

Answer (score 4):

To get it into a variable use myShort.Value after checking myShort.HasValue

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually trying to protect against SomeBusinessObject being null? If so, nullable types won't help you there. You still need to check whether your SomeBusinessObject is null.

I'm assuming that this is the case because if UserBlah returns a short then it'll never be null (as short is not a nullable type).

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget about the null coalescing operator.

```
short myShort = SomeBusinessObject.UserBlah ?? 0;
```

if SomeBusinessObject.UserBlah is null, it just passes the value to the right of ?? so you can default it to something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

`myShort` will be `null` if the business object returns `null`.

You can't reference `myShort` as a value type directly, so this is OK.

You can use `myShort.HasValue` to see if `myShort` is `null` or not.

Use `myShort.Value` to get the value. It will throw an exception if no value is defined.

You can use `GetValueOrDefault()` and pass in a default to get a value even if none is defined (`null`). This function returns the value you passed in if the nullable type is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

myShort will only be null if `UserBlah` is implicitly convertible to `Nullable<Int16>` and it is set to null, in which case it will not break unless you try to access a member of `myShort.Value`.

You can also do this:

```
short defaultValue = 0;
short myShort      = SomeBusinessObject.UserBlah ?? defaultValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

[Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx)